# Indefinite Number of Fields

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, pymysql

I'm scraping a web-page, and there will be an indefinite number of related elements on each page that I plan to stick in a table of their own. However, how do you dynamically create `scrapy.Field()` elements to deal with this? Or do you not need to or?

*Example*

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I'm scraping profile pages of random people. Some of those people have pets, some don't. Some have tons of pets, others just have one. How do I deal with this? How do I dynamically create as many `pet` fields as are needed?

```
name = scrapy.Field()
age = scrapy.Field()
height = scrapy.Field()
pet = scrapy.Field()
# pet1 = scrapy.Field()
# pet2 = scrapy.Field()
# continues indefinitely
```

Answer (score 0):

create two item types:

```
class Person(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    age = scrapy.Field()
    height = scrapy.Field()

class Pet(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    pet = scrapy.Field()
```

Then for each `Person` you can create multiple `Pet`s

Comment: of course i can create an indefinite number of `Pet()` instances, but hm.. i'm going to be scraping all the "profiles" and all of their "pets" at once, so how would it work exactly?? the spider processes the response and then the items get sent to the items pipeline. in my spider, should i put all of the pets in a list (i.e. `item['pets'] = ['list', 'of', 'pets', 'whatever']`) and then process that list in `items.py`??

Comment: @Anthony there are many ways you can hook that into the project - maybe using `process_item`?

Comment: @Anthony another option is as you said just add the pets to a list and then separate when exporting with a custom exporter... many options!

Comment: (i'm new to python/scrapy if that wasn't obvious.) by any chance, can you point me to an example of this somewhere on the web? in the ['Architecture Overview'](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) section of the documentation, it doesn't explicitly state when `pipelines.py` is executed? or is `pipelines.py` simply an "item pipeline"?? also, i'm assuming `items.py` is executed around the time the spider is launched to initiate the fields, and if that's the case, is there a way to create fields on the fly?

Comment: the issue with your solution is that if `items.py`, in which `class Person` and `class Pet` are declared, executes before the Spider even begins crawling, then the fields are created before i would even know how many pets a person might have

Comment: @Anthony my idea was to generate two separate tables of results "people" and "pets", not fields in a single table - what is your destination format? most formats don't allow arbitrary number of fields. Scrapy is a framework, it calls your functions when needed. `.py` files are not "executed" in any sequence, they are imported and the framework will call your functions when needed/some event happens.

Comment: that is my goal: a separate table for "pets." but via the `process_items` function in `pipelines.py` i'm inserting the data into a mysql database. hm.. i think you're wrong about the `.py` files not being executed in any particular order; for instance, the documentation (the link i shared with u in my last post) makes it seems as if `middlewares.py` is executed before `pipelines.py` (i added a new tag to indicate that now)

Comment: @Anthony sorry, this is just wording difference - you are correct, but it is not `pipelines.py` that is executed, what is executed is the pipelines you defined. They can be defined anywhere and registered in the framework. Usually you define them in `pipelines.py` but nothing forces you to define them there.

Comment: If you put the pets in a list, and when writing to database you just separate them? You have to think of scrapy as a loose guideline - nothing forces you to create the items, you could just create any kind of object and persist it.

Comment: yeah, i know the framework imports specific scripts and auto executes their classes and functions. was just semantics!! the "item pipeline" functionality (`items.py`) is so goddamn convenient tho. it neatly passes all of the code forward to be processed without a hiccup. how do i make my own variables that i declare in my Spider persist, so that they're passed to my `pipelines.py`? do all i need to do is yield it as an iterable?